# shell - pass function name as parameter

Tags: shell

I created a shell script which needed some interactivity in it, so I made the following function:

```
function check(){
    echo $1
    read ans
    if [ -z $ans ] || [ $ans = "y" ]; then 
        $2 ${*:3}  
    fi 
}
```

Now I can use this with:

```
check "shall I greet?" say_hello oz123 stackoverflow 
check "Do you leave?" say_goodbye
```

Given the functions:

```
function say_hello(){

    echo hello $1
    echo hello $2

}

function say_goodbye(){
    echo "Goodbye..."
}
```

I came up with `check` by a simple trial, proofing if I can give a function name as a parameter to function. Apparently this is working, but I don't understand why. Can you explain why?

Comment: When you write `say_goodbye` at the `$` (or whatever) prompt you are running the command by string name. Why wouldn't that work from another function?

Comment: I was expecting the shell to first evaluate the function, but apparently the shell is smarter then I thought.

Comment: You aren't telling the shell to evaluate any function (not that that's really even a thing). You are writing a word. Words are only commands when they start a line. Think about `echo echo word`? That doesn't display `word` it displays `echo word`, etc. Compare that to `echo $(echo word)` though (where you are explicitly telling the shell to run a command from part of your line).

Answer (score 1):

To expand Etan's comment, here is what man bash says exactly:

> *SHELL GRAMMAR*
>
> ```
> Simple Commands  
> A simple command is a sequence of optional  variable  assignments 
> followed by  blank-separated  words and redirections, and terminated by a
> control operator. The first word specifies the command to be executed,
> and  is  passed  as  argument  zero. The remaining words are passed as
> arguments to the invoked command.
> ```

I wish I knew this earlier, it can make bash scripts much more constructed and easier to write and read.